# AWS: Code deploy in Virginia region and ec2 in singapore region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

I am learning `aws code deploy` . Currently I have test and prod server in `Singapore region`. I want to use deploy my code in prod server.

I found that code-deploy is not available in 'Singapore' region, so I switch to 'Virginia'.

So when I am configuring code-deploy then I am not finding my `prod` server in "attach your ec2 instance".

I am sure it is because of difference in regions.

Can any one help me how can I use code-deploy even if i want my server to be in `Singapore` region ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you mean to write "then I am *not* finding my prod server..."?

You can not use CodeDeploy in one region to manage an instance in another region.

You have a few options:

- wait for CodeDeploy to become available in Singapore
- run your prod server in a region that supports CodeDeploy
- try using something like ElasticBeanstalk, until such time as CodeDeploy is available

Comment: Thanks @MIke ,, yeah I meant 'I am not finding my prod server' .. I am editing the question .. thanks

Comment: I am also facing same issue ! My jenkins is in Oregon region and I want to deploy using AWS code on instance in Mumbai region. I have created Code Deploy app in Mumbai region but now I am not able to call this app from my jenkins server as it's in Oregon region